# Airflow AWS connection without access key and secret id in K8

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, airflow

How to trigger a DAG in Airflow-2.0 from Kubernetes to access a lambda without access key and secret id. Tried with attaching annotations on pod with IAM role but when triggering DAG getting error Unable to locate credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding the annotation on pod having role-arn as its value that I want to connect the pod and lambda

Answer (score 0):

somewhat similar question, I'm trying to trigger a docker image using kubernetes pod operator on Airflow. I'm adding IAM role in annotations like this

```
annotations={"iam.amazonaws.com/role":Variable.get(key=UOM_S3_IAM_ROLE)},
```

It works at times and fails randomly with an error that unable to locate credentials. How exactly were you able to resolve this